# Export of group = multiband raster to another format not works in GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, landsat

I am really new in GRASS and my question is really basic but I don't realize where I am wrong.

I have a set of single layers in my PERMANENT from some Landsat images (1 Landsat = 7 one layer rasters). I would like to export group (named "stack" in R) of these layers = forming 1 Landsat image to .img. I suppose the following steps to do it in GRASS:

1. Import single layer to GRASS (there is no way to import multiple layer in one time?): **r.in.gdal**
2. Create "group" = multiband raster from singleband rasters: **i.group**.
3. Export multiband raster as new format: **r.out.gdal**

My problem is why when I use *i.group* I see that actually I have a group of my bands:

[image]

but if I want to export group of my layers a see only single bands, not the group!!
[image]

Please, any idea **how to create and export multiband raster to .img in GRASS**? (and try to avoid python?). As my bands are in GRASS format, I can't easily do the job in software more convenient for me.

Comment: I have always found GRASS GIS to be a confusing bit of software. Which tool is it that is only available there?

Comment: for all here mentionned tools I can find an alternative. Only I can´t find/store the result of "i.group" and therefore I can´t export it as whole raster stack... I can export my layers by layer but it so unefficient and boring...

Comment: I was thinking for of the tools that you didn't mention. There must be a reason why you are using the GRASS GIS GUI and not QGIS, GRASS GIS commandline, R or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide here commands but you can just find the given options in the dialogs. According to your question I suppose you already have a GRASS imagery group. So, I will just focus on exporting the group into a multi-band image format.

First, see what are the output formats are supported:

```
r.out.gdal -l
```

This will give you long list which contains also HFA/`.img` format which you want:

```
HFA (rw+): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
```

Next, see what groups you have:

```
g.list type=group
```

In my case, that's only one group:

```
lsat7_2000
```

Just to be sure check which rasters are in the group:

```
i.group group=lsat7_2000 -l
```

In my case, it is:

```
group <lsat7_2000> references the following raster maps
-------------
<lsat7_2000_10@landsat>    <lsat7_2000_20@landsat>    
<lsat7_2000_30@landsat>    <lsat7_2000_40@landsat>    
<lsat7_2000_50@landsat>    <lsat7_2000_61@landsat>    
<lsat7_2000_70@landsat>    <lsat7_2000_80@landsat>    
-------------
```

So, we know that the name of the group is `lsat7_2000` and name of the format in GDAL is `HFA`.

Now you can fill `lsat7_2000` into *Name of raster map (or group) to export* field in the `r.out.gdal` dialog, `HFA` into *Raster data format to write* field and name (and path) of output file into *Name for output raster file* field.

In command line, it looks like this:

```
r.out.gdal input=lsat7_2000 output=some/path/landsat_2000.img format=HFA
```

The source of your confusion might be that the `input` option (field) of `r.out.gdal` says *raster map (or group)* but the GUI offers only raster maps. However, the GUI will allow you to write there anything manually (i.e. not select from the list), so you can put there the name of the group.

Comment: Hi @wenzeslaus, great, it works! However, the process is too slow (30 min to export one image). Please, is there possibility to reduce the time? I think that is caused because of the 16 bit pixel depth.

Comment: I don't know about a way of reducing the export time. There is definitively a lot of IO (disk operations), so this is why the process is slow. Using SSD disk might be helpful. What is the size of your area (number of cells)?

Comment: It is whole Landsat scene. However, thank you very much, it work :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. The only thing to make it faster (besides better hardware) is to run more `r.out.gdal` commands in parallel in case you have more than one GRASS imagery group. However, since the operation is IO bound, the performance of parallel solution depends on the combination of hard disks you are using (SSD disk or more different hard disks might improve it, but it might be just the same). It might also depend on the file system used but I really cannot elaborate on that.

Comment: If you would be doing it over and over, then it might be better to look at `r.external` which can link the data into GRASS Database.